# Is there a term for words that can be both a noun and a verb?

Tags: single-word-requests

For instance: One can attend an "auction", or you can "auction" something off.

Comment: English is one of those languages where virtually every noun can be verbified. It's a form of derivation since such words derive from base words. It's called [nominalisation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization) but I'm not 100% sure. (Polysemous is pretty close.)

Answer (score -1):

Such words are called Gerund's. Gerund is a non-finite verb form used to make a verb phrase that can serve in place of a noun phrase.

A gerund is an instance when a verb is being used in a very particular way – as a noun!

You do this by changing the infinitive form of the verb, and adding “ing” at the end.

Examples 
"I enjoy writing – it’s my favourite hobby.”

Comment: In English a gerund always ends in -ing, which the noun **auction** does not. Therefore it is not a gerund!